# ¿Como puedo llamar a un metodo de application_controller desde otro metodo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

Tengo un controlador de usuarios estoy usando Rails 6 API  y estoy usando la gema JWTSessions para autenticar usuarios en la documentacion me indica que agrege el siguiente metodo:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include JWTSessions::RailsAuthorization
  rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :bad_request
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :unprocessable_entity
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
  rescue_from JWTSessions::Errors::Unauthorized, with: :not_authorized
  rescue_from JWTSessions::Errors::ClaimsVerification, with: :forbidden
  rescue_from ResetPasswordError, with: :not_authorized

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(payload['user_id'])
  end

end
```

Al mandar llamar el metodo **current_user** desde users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_access_request!

  def me
    render json: current_user
  end
end
```

La ruta para llamar al metodo me es la siguiente **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'refresh', controller: :refresh, action: :create
  post 'signin', controller: :signin, action: :create
  post 'signup', controller: :signup, action: :create
  delete 'signin', controller: :signin, action: :destroy

  get 'me', controller: :users, action: :me

end
```

He logeado correctamente al usuario pero al mandar llamar el metodo  **me**
obtengo el siguiente error

> undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Me podrian ayudar porque me marca el error si estoy añadiendo los metodos correspondientes 
gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes tu `current_user` como `private`, por tanto solo puedes llamarlo desde `ApplicationController`. Si quieres llamarlo desde los controladores que heredan desde `ApplicationController`, debes declarar el método como `protected` o dejarlo como público.